# How can I display seconds at bootloader?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, boot, fasm, bochs

I'm working on education project about writing a simple assembler bootloader.
What I'm using:

- fasm
- bochs
- script to build

```
fasm.exe boot.asm boot.bin
del disk.img
fsutil file createnew disk.img 1474560
dd if=boot.bin of=disk.img
```

- command to run the bochs
  `bochs.exe -q -f bochsrc.bxrc`

I need to set a timer of seconds at the right.
After researching I need to catch `0x08` interrupt and handle it by means of replacing `0x1c` which is at the end of `0x08` returning `iret` by default.

At the start of program I tried to replace `0x1c` in the Interrupt Vector Table

```
use16

org 0x7c00

boot__code16:
    offset_1ch equ 0x1c * 4
    
    cli
    xor ax,ax
    mov es, ax  
    mov es, ax
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov ss,ax
    mov ax, boot__code16
    mov sp,ax

    mov ax, offset_1ch
    mov [es:offset_1ch], ax
    push cs
    pop ax
    mov [es:offset_1ch+2], ax
    
    sti
```

And then to display smth:

```
    mov ax, 0002h
    int 10h
    
    mov dx,0h
    call SetCursor
    
    mov bp, loading_str
    mov cx, 10
    call Print
```

What problem I have now:
If I replace `0x1c` the emulator will display nothing.
If I try to replace another interrupt (0x1f for instance) it will work until I call it in code and then it will display nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

UPD
I've chaned some code:

```
    cli
    xor ax,ax
    mov es, ax  
    mov es, ax
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov ss,ax
    mov ax, boot__code16
    mov sp,ax

    mov ax, timer
    mov [offset_1ch], ax
    sti
```

```
timer:
    iret
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. 1/ you don't seem to follow the structure of a boot sector (there is data at some specific place, etc.) 2/ You replace the interrupt vector with the address cs:70h, what do you expect it's going to do if there is no code at this address? To me, the first `offset_1ch` in `mov ax, offset_1ch`, `mov [es:offset_1ch], ax` looks like a bug: it should be `mov ax, offset_h`, where `offset_h` is the address in the cs segment of *your* interrupt handler.

Comment: Really it looks like a bug, I've changed code, but It doesn't work. I will add my changes to question

Answer (score 0):

I've found decision.
That is simplier than I expected, I was needing only change memory using segment and offset.

```
    cli
    xor ax,ax
    mov es, ax  
    mov es, ax
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov ss,ax
    mov ax, boot__code16
    mov sp,ax

    mov ax, timer
    mov [offset_1ch], ax
    mov [offset_1ch+2], es
    sti
```

Comment: 1. You don't have to use `mov es, ax` thrice. 2. You can use `mov sp, boot__code16` without involving `ax`. 3. You should set `sp` in the immediately following instruction after the one that sets `ss`. 4. Like 2 you can directly use `mov word [offset_1ch], timer` without involving `ax`.

Comment: Good advice, I'll change my code according your comments